# android scrollview with margins?

Tags: android, scrollview, margins

I may be really thick here but is it possible to have a scroll view that has say a 100 pixel margin top and bottom so that the contents just scrolls in that area and not into the top and bottom margin?

whatever I try when I scroll the content it scrolls into the top and bottom margins

Something like a scroll able text box?

Any Ideas

Mark

Comment: You could place your scroll view in the middle of some empty views that way you force it in the middle; Setting exact values in views is not always a good idea, so using margin top and bottom might not be good for small devices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `padding` instead of `margin` that have a padding of **100px** top and bottom

**sample:**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingBottom="100dp"
    android:paddingTop="100dp" >
```

Comment: @user3422687 put the scrollView inside a View and set the background of that view